# Jackson annotation to deserialize delimited string to list

Tags: java, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I have a string delimited by a semi-colon

```
value1; value2; value3; etc..
```

I am using Jackson ObjectMapper to deserialize the json response into a POJO but am having issues figuring out how to tell Jackson that it should split this string property on ';'

Is this feature supported by Jackson?

Hoping for something like

```
public class POJO {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY, delimitOn = ";")
    private List<String> category;
}
```

I also tried my own deserializer based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171539/jackson-json-property-string-to-instance) but Jackson complained about not being able to convert String to List - maybe I did this wrong?

```
public class DelimitedStringDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<List<String>> {

    protected DelimitedStringDeserializer() {
        super(List.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> deserialize(org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser jp, org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException {
        return Arrays.asList(jp.getText().split(";"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson json property (string) to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171539/jackson-json-property-string-to-instance)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar updated my post, i did try this but maybe I did this wrong

Comment: You need to tell Jackson about the deserializer. Google it, there’re literally hundreds of examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247639/deserialize-arraylist-from-string-using-jackson

Comment: @ZiaullhaqSavanur thank you, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247639/deserialize-arraylist-from-string-using-jackson#answer-10251039

it's a little clunky but it'll work